# Algolia Not Includes Search

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, full-text-search, algolia

I have a datatset that looks like so

```
[ 
   { 
      "title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
      "content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
   },
   { 
      "title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
      "content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
   }
]
```

```js
const keywords = [ 
   "pariatur",
   "fugiat"
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to find all results that do not contain the words specified in the `keywords` array. So from the example above the end result should just be the first object only since the seconds object contains the keywords `pariatur` as well as `fugiat`.

What I've tried so far that isn't really working.

```js
   await index.setSettings({
      searchableAttributes: ["title,content"],
      attributesForFaceting: ["title", "content"],
    });

    const result = await index.search({
      filters: "NOT content:pariatur AND NOT title:fugiat",
    })
```